Describe all cones in $\mathbb R^n$ that are simplicial and cosimplicial.
For any finite set of vectors $(v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n)$, let's define:
$Cone(v_1,…,v_k)= \{λ_1v_1+…+λ_kv_k,∣,λ_1,…,λ_k \ge 0\}$ and $Poly(v_1,…,v_k)= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n ∣(v_i, x) \ge 0, \forall i=1,…,k \}$
A cone $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is called simplicial (respectively cosimplicial) if $C = \text{Cone}(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ (respectively $C = \text{Poly}(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$) for some linearly independent set of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Describe all cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are simultaneously simplicial and cosimplicial.
I was able to prove that such a cone must consist exactly of n linearly independent vectors, but I don't know how to show that all simplicial cones generated by $n$ vectors are also cosimplicial.

For $n > 0$, a cone must be infinite, so it can't consist of just $n$ vectors. As a hint to simplify the problem, you may as well take ${v_i}$ to be the standard basis $ {\mathbb{e}_i}$ in one of the two definitions and then draw some pictures for small $n$.

simply characterise those cones that are both simplicial and cosimplicial.

"For >0, a cone must be infinite, so it can't consist of just  vectors" I want to say that for simplicial cone $C = Cone(v_1, ..., v_k) $ to be cosimplical it is necessary that $k = n$
